# Integer Parsing is not working for converting binary to decimal

Tags: java, android, string, binary

I'm working on an app that will calculate binary two number. I'm using two `EditText` for getting input. Then send the value to two strings. Then using `Integer.parseInt(input, 2)` for converting the number to integer for calculation. But when I use Integer.parseInt the app crashes.

XML:

```
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Enter 1st Value"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Enter 1st Value"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

Java:

```
EditText input1, input2;
int number1, number2, number3;
String string1, string2, string3;

    input1 = findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    input2 = findViewById(R.id.edit2);
    result = findViewById(R.id.result);

    string1 = input1.getText().toString();
    string2 = input2.getText().toString();

    number1 = Integer.parseInt(string1, 2);
    number2 = Integer.parseInt(string2, 2);

    number3 = number1 + number2;
```

When I use  `number1 = Integer.parseInt(string1, 2);` & `number2 = Integer.parseInt(string2, 2);` app crashes.

When I remove that part, then the app doesn't crash.

I've searched various solutions but found nothing working.

Note: when I set the string to some value then `Inter.parseInt` doesn't cause crash.

Comment: Can you shoe the stack trace?

Comment: You need to catch any potential number format exceptions. If it doesn't crash when you set it to a value, then it works, you just need to handle the cases the string is null or not a number

Comment: And what is the content of `R.id.edit1` and `R.id.edit2`? Does it work if it's a valid binary number?

Comment: submitted @dan1st

Comment: @Tyler, How can I do that?

Comment: No. It doesn't work. App crashes when i use string = input.getText().toString(). But when I use value like string = "10" then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before number1 = Integer.parseInt(string1, 2);
you should check that string1 is a valid number.

At least I would do something like:

```
try {
   if (string1 != null && string1.trim().equals("")) {
      number1 = Integer.parseInt(string1.trim(), 2);
   }
   // check other strings...
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something if exception occur
}
```

Note:
At onCreate() these value (string1, string2, string3) will be probably null or empty and they will generate an exception.

Comment: you trim `string1` when testing but not when parsing. Are you sure?

Comment: @dan1st: ops, I forgot it. I have edited the answer now

Comment: That helps. I used input length != 0 statement then parse the integer.